# Parametric subsetting and assignment

Tags: r, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

In my problem I need to assign some values to a data.frame possibly out of its bounds on the basis of a given function arguments.

To implement a parametric assignment one could define:

```
ass=function(x,i,j,a){
  # some operations on x,i,j,a 
  `[<-`(x,i,j,a) 
}
```

or

```
ass=function(x,i,j,a){
  # some operations on x,i,j 
  do.call(`[<-`, list(x,i,j,a))
}
```

The problem comes when I need to emulate `x[,j]` or `x[i,]`.  In some cases `TRUE` will work, i.e.:

```
`[<-`(x,T,j,a); `[<-`(x,i,T,a)
```

is like:

```
x[,j]=a; x[i,]=a;
```

Now assume `x` is a `n*3` data.frame, I can assign out of bounds without any problems, e.g.:

```
`[<-`(x,T,4,0)
```

still works like

```
x[,4]=0
```

But:

```
`[<-`(x,T,4:5,0)
```

gives a "subscript out of bounds" error, while

```
 x[,4:5]=0
```

works.

How can I "hack" the the notation  `"[<-"(x,i,j,a)` or `do.call("[<-", list(x,i,j,a))` in order to take all `i` (or all `j`)?

Comment: I'm curious. In what sense do you mean *parametric subsetting*?

Comment: **EDIT** To select *all* the rows or columns, just leave the argument blank, i.e. `\`[<-\`(x,,4:5,0)`. I would guess that by providing the `i` or `j` argument for rows or columns which don't yet exist, you are trying to subset on a column or row index that doesn't exist. The `T` value is actually being recycled to match the length of the `i` or `j` of your `data.frame`, Which is why it works on indices that *do* exist. e.g. try `\`[<-\`(x,c(T,F),1,0)` to set every other row to zero of the first column.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon: the problem is what value should I pass as `i`, so that it disappears from `x,i,j,a`? Using the TRUE trick I can use `ass(x,TRUE,j,a)` or say `ass(x,1,j,a)`.  Currently I use an `if` to rewrite `x,i,j,a`, like `x,,j,a` or `x,i,,a`.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon: Also how do I use the do.call method with a missing i (or j)?  `do.call(`[<-`, list(x,,j,a))` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Formal restatement of the problem

Given the integers `i,j`  and the matrix/data.frame `x`, find  the `m` such that:

```
x[i,m]; x[m,j]; x[m,m]
```

are identical resp. to:

```
x[i,]; x[,j]; x[,]
```

This should of course apply also to replacements, i.e. for:

```
x[*] = value
```

and with the syntax `` `[` `` and `` `[<-` ``  or the related `do.call`.

### Investigation of the problem

If you are not interested to know what is under the hood, you can go straight to  the proposed solution.

Since `` `[` `` and `` `[<-` `` are functions, `m` should be considered as a missing value for the arguments  `i, j`. Therefore one should create an "artificial" missing value.
 What happens upon inspection of actual missing values in a function?

```
f=function(i,j){
   cat ('A) ');  print(match.call())
   cat ('B) ');  print(sys.call())
   cat ('C)\n'); print(as.list(sys.call()))
}
```

When using a comma without a preceding argument, we get:

```
f(,2)

#A) f(j = 2)
#B) f(, 2)
#C)
#[[1]]
#f
# 
#[[2]]
# 
# 
#[[3]]
#[1] 2
```

The second element of the `sys.call` list seems empty! So we try to capture this value:

```
f=function(a,b) as.list(sys.call())[[2]] 
m=f(,)
```

and:

```
m                   
Error: argument "m" is missing, with no default
```

...never an error was so welcomed.

### Proposed solution

Set:

```
m=(function(a,b) as.list(sys.call())[[2]])(,)
```

`m` is now an *artificial missing value*. It operates like the empty space near the comma when subsetting. In fact:

```
x=matrix(1:12, ncol=3)    

x[m,m]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    5    9
#[2,]    2    6   10
#[3,]    3    7   11
#[4,]    4    8   12

x[1, m ]
#[1] 1 5 9

x[m, 1 ]
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

So far, while more formal, this method does not offer more than the recycling trickery `x[T,T]`, `x[1,T]`,  `x[T,1]`.  But, when the workaround does not work:

```
x=data.frame(x)
x[T,4:5]=0
#Error in `*tmp*`[[j]] : subscript out of bounds
```

the artificial missing value works:

```
x[m,4:5]=0
x
#  X1 X2 X3 V4 V5
#1  1  5  9  0  0
#2  2  6 10  0  0
#3  3  7 11  0  0
#4  4  8 12  0  0
```